# How to enable add-on service during unattended SDL Sites 9.1 installation

Tags: installation, sites-9.1, add-on

We are currently building setup scripts for an unattended SDL Sites 9.1 installation.

The installer provides a series of switches to enable/disable certain functionality, as described here
https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v2/GUID-B9FFD1EC-A598-42C7-92BF-C24D9B21B473

Unfortunately, I couldn't find an option to enable/configure the Add-On service this way. It is possible to configure this via the regular installation wizard.

Is this possible through the unattended install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's possible to Configure Add-On Service on the Content Manager side to install the SDL Tridion Sites by scripted to install silently then it is required to pass

```
ADDON_SERVICE_URL=http://localhost:83
```

Indeed, The documentation it was missing, I will raise this internally to update the documentation, also left the comment in the documentation section.

I too blogged about this "[Installation of Add on Service in SDL Tridion Sites 9.1](https://velmuruganarjunan.wordpress.com/2019/09/13/installation-of-add-on-service-in-sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/)"

I hope it helps.